# is it possible to set hidden attribute on file/folder for windows from linux?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I want to hide 1 folder in my pen drive for Windows but from Ubuntu, is it possible if yes then how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Linux tool for changing DOS/Windows file attributes?](https://superuser.com/questions/321109/is-there-a-linux-tool-for-changing-dos-windows-file-attributes)

Answer (score 3):

`fatattr` can do it for VFAT. Not sure about NTFS.

Answer (score 2):

you could try renaming to ./.whatever then renaming back with the hide_dot_files mount option enabled...i haven't seen another way to do it yet...

Comment: http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/ says respecting/setting the hidden attribute is supported, but they don't say a way to DO it.  this is my workaround

Answer (score 0):

Try my shell script, which is a (mostly) re-implementation of `attrib` command in Windows.

This uses `system.ntfs_attrib_be` attribute from NTFS-3G, so you need `gatfattr` and `setfattr` utilities from your distro (in Debian/Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install attr`).

But after that, just use it without remembering the bit masks, e.g.

`./ntfs_attr.sh -h -s some_file_in_ntfs_volume`

<s>https://gist.github.com/Explorer09/ac4bf6838c271a9968b3</s>
(Migrating to GitLab; old link might cease to work.)
https://gitlab.com/snippets/1720133

Notes:

`/L` option in attrib in Windows is implemented here, see the help in script for details.

`/S` and `/S /D` are (intentionally) not implemented. Try find(1) with this script instead.

By the way, I think this question could be merged with this one: [Is there a Linux tool for changing DOS/Windows file attributes?](https://superuser.com/questions/321109/is-there-a-linux-tool-for-changing-dos-windows-file-attributes)