# Is there a Linux tool for changing DOS/Windows file attributes?

Tags: linux, windows, ntfs

I often use a Linux LiveCD (or Puppy on a pen drive) to disinfect Windows machines that are infested with various malware.  However, once the malware is gone, you still need to deal with the modifications it might have made, and sadly Linux isn't so great for that.

The recent crop of FakeAV programs try to freak the user out by making everything disappear - they set the "Don't show hidden or system files" option (and protect it with a Group Policy), and then they set the hidden/system attributes on every file in Documents and Settings\UserName.

What I'd like - but haven't found - is a Linux tool to reset those attributes.  I suppose if I ran Samba, and shared the NTFS volume, and set my options correctly, I could probably do this from a DOS or Windows client... but that's a real pain, and anyway I'm not so sure about sharing an NTFS volume via Samba.  Any way to do it directly?

Edit:
OK - sounds like **setfattr(1)** is what I need; however, it looks to me like I'd be setting a value bitmap directly, rather than applying a mask.  Am I understanding that correctly - and if so, what (if anything) could I do to implement a mask?
In other words, some files might legitimately be Read-Only; some might have the Archive bit set.  How do I *only* unset Hidden or System, without touching the others - like **attrib -s -h** at the Windows command line?  If the only way to do it is to **getfattr** first, and then decide which parameters to pass to **setfattr**... well, I would hope not.

Comment: So it might be my security centered frame of mind... but the words "disinfect" and "infested" make me want to immediately state "wipe and reinstall/reimage".

Comment: try [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you’re feeling (just like me) `setfattr` is too low level and error-prone and want something like `attrib` in Windows or `chmod` in Linux, then [`fatattr`](https://gitlab.com/Terseus/fatattr) seems to be the right tool.

Its [usage](https://gitlab.com/Terseus/fatattr#usage) is simple, for example:

```sh
fatattr +R FILE  # set FILE read-only
fatattr -H FILE  # set FILE not hidden
```

To get [`fatattr` on Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fatattr), simply run (with [Universe repository enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)):

```
sudo apt install fatattr
```

Comment: For me it keeps failing with `Invalid argument` when I pass a path to a file located on an NTFS partition. Does this work only with FAT?

Comment: The parameters are *lowercase:* `fatattr [-+rhsvda67] files...`

Answer (score 10):

NTFS-3G includes the `setfattr` command:

```
setfattr -h -v 0x00000000 -n system.ntfs_attrib_be target-file
```

should clear all attributes (the last argument *target-file* should be changed, of course.) See [here](http://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/extend-attr.html#ntfsattributes) for a list of available attributes and how to set them.

Comment: The link no longer works

Comment: http://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/extend-attr.html#ntfsattributes

Answer (score 5):

`setfattr` probably works for NTFS file systems, but in case someone needs to do the same for FAT (vfat/fat16/fat32) file systems, see `mtools` package. That will do the job!

Answer (score 4):

Try my shell script, which is a (mostly) re-implementation of `attrib` command in Windows.

This uses `system.ntfs_attrib_be` attribute from NTFS-3G, so you need `gatfattr` and `setfattr` utilities from your distro (in Debian/Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install attr`).

But after that, just use it without remembering the bit masks, e.g.

`./ntfs_attr.sh -h -s some_file_in_ntfs_volume`

<s>https://gist.github.com/Explorer09/ac4bf6838c271a9968b3</s>
(Migrating to GitLab; old link might cease to work.)
https://gitlab.com/snippets/1720133

Notes:

`/L` option in attrib in Windows is implemented here, see the help in script for details.

`/S` and `/S /D` are (intentionally) not implemented. Try find(1) with this script instead.

Comment: I'm not in a place where I can test it at the moment, but this sounds like EXACTLY what I had in mind.  Upvoting now, will accept as soon as I've tested it.  Thanks!  (

Answer (score 3):

If you're mounting the filesystem with a suitably recent version of NTFS-3G, you can [use `getfattr` and `setfattr` to access those attributes](http://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/extend-attr.html).

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add something I used recently.

If you are trying to modify MSDOS attributes on a FAT16/32 filesystem (I was using Git Bash and I was trying to unhide the files on my fat32 flash drive that was hidden by a malware), you can use **fatattr**

The command syntax to unhide files is quite simply.

> fatattr -h /path-to-your-file/file-name

Other available options can be checked [here](https://github.com/Terseus/fatattr).

It can be downloaded from [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/fatattr/1.0/)

Just put it in your git bash binaries directory and you are good to go!